# How to undo clipping vertices by applied mirror modifier

Tags: modeling, modifiers, mirror

So I applied it way back ago, now I saw it and I can't rip it using v

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're talking about cancelling the clipping in the modifier while having it active (There 's a button for it in the Modifiers Tab --> **Mirror Modifier** --> **Clipping**), one option could be selecting the mesh that you want to be separated and then pressing: **P** --> **Separate By** --> **Material** (for example). Hopefully this useful in some manner :)

Comment: I am talking about the first one but after I already applied the modifier.

Comment: If it's no longer in the undo (CTRL-Z) list, there's no way to undo it once the modifier has been applied. If hat's not what you mean, please edit your question and add an image to show what you mean.